# Prevent server terminating in client (golang) server (Java) application

Tags: java, tcp, go, client-server, tcpclient

I have a simple echo-server in Java:

```
 int portNumber = 4444;

    try (
        ServerSocket serverSocket =
            new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(inputLine);
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
            + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

and a simple golang client:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("start client")
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:4444")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Connection error", err)
    }
    conn.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    conn.Close()
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

When I start the server and then run the client, the server echo's "hello world" as expected but then the server exits/terminates.

**Q. How do I prevent this Java termination and force the server to continually wait for more client requests?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the client terminates, the `readLine` on server side will result in the end of the stream.  So if you want the server to continuously listen for new connections the simply put the above server code in a endless loop.

e.g.

```
while (true) {
   // above code
}
```

For a play application that would be adequate.

Comment: Changed to: while (true) {
         inputLine = in.readLine();
             if(inputLine != null){
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
             }

            } Now it prints once, doesn't terminate, but doesnt print any more.

Comment: No, the meaning of `above code` means ALL of the `above server code`.  It has to re-establish the server socket